# Android - How to target different architectures with Affective SDK?

Tags: android, gesture-recognition, affdex-sdk

I've been playing around with the [Affective Android SDK](https://knowledge.affectiva.com/docs/getting-started-with-the-emotion-sdk-for-android) and found that once the apk is built it only contains the native library for **armeabi-v7** architecture
[image]
does it mean that if we use this SDK we are going to be only targeting users with only this type of phones?

Have anyone managed to use Affective SDK on **x86** and **mips** architectures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Affectiva's SDKs are packaged differently depending on the OS being used. At the moment Android support is limited to the arm architecture.
Linux on the other had as both x86 and arm architecture support:
https://affectiva.readme.io/docs/getting-started-with-the-affectiva-sdk-for-linux

Comment: Thanks Matt, I've been doing some research and it seems that the arm and related platforms are the most used since a few years.